# Spinner selecting step by step depend on selected value

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have 3 spinners and depend on each other like that;

- Category1
- Category2
- Category3

When user select Category1, 2.spinner should show that;

- Category1-1
- Category1-2
- Category1-3

And user select Category1-2, 3.spinner should show that;

- Category1-1-1
- Category1-1-2
- Category1-1-3

> I implement this way, but it is too long
>
> so i want to any suggestion for more efficient code

```
public class BookActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
Spinner sp1,sp2,sp3;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);
    sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp1);
    sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp2);
    sp3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp3);
    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
    list.add("Category1");
    list.add("Category2");
    list.add("Category3");

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp1.setAdapter(adapter);
    sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                           long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Toast.makeText(this, "YOUR SELECTION IS : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    fillSpinnerList(parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());

}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

public void fillSpinnerList(String selectedSpinnerName){

    if(selectedSpinnerName =="Category1" ){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Category1-1");
        list.add("Category1-2");
        list.add("Category1-3");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp2.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
    if(selectedSpinnerName =="Category2" ){

        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Category2-1");
        list.add("Category2-2");
        list.add("Category2-3");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp2.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


    }
    if(selectedSpinnerName =="Category3" ){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Category3-1");
        list.add("Category3-2");
        list.add("Category3-3");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp2.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
    if(selectedSpinnerName =="Category1-1" ){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Category1-1-1");
        list.add("Category1-1-2");
        list.add("Category1-1-3");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp3.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
    if(selectedSpinnerName =="Category1-2" ){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Category1-2-1");
        list.add("Category1-2-2");
        list.add("Category1-2-3");

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp3.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
    if(selectedSpinnerName =="Category1-3" ){
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add("Category1-3-1");
        list.add("Category1-3-2");
        list.add("Category1-3-3");
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp3.setAdapter(adapter);
        sp3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refactor it like that. It's still long as a part of it can be generalised but it's more readable.

BookActivity

```
public class BookActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner sp1, sp2, sp3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);
        sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp1);
        sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp2);
        sp3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp3);

        initSpinner1();
    }

    private void initSpinner1() {
        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("Category1");
        list.add("Category2");
        list.add("Category3");

        initSpinner(sp1, list, new SpinnerListener.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(String itemName) {
                initSpinner2(itemName);
            }
        });
    }

    private void initSpinner2(String selectedCategory) {
        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        switch (selectedCategory) {
            case "Category1":
                list.add("Category1-1");
                list.add("Category1-2");
                list.add("Category1-3");
                break;
            case "Category2":
                list.add("Category2-1");
                list.add("Category2-2");
                list.add("Category2-3");
                break;
            case "Category3":
                list.add("Category3-1");
                list.add("Category3-2");
                list.add("Category3-3");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        initSpinner(sp2, list, new SpinnerListener.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(String itemName) {
                initSpinner3(itemName);
            }
        });
    }

    public void initSpinner3(String selectedCategory) {
        final List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        switch (selectedCategory) {
            case "Category1-1":
                list.add("Category1-1-1");
                list.add("Category1-1-2");
                list.add("Category1-1-3");
                break;
            case "Category1-2":
                list.add("Category1-2-1");
                list.add("Category1-2-2");
                list.add("Category1-2-3");
                break;
            case "Category1-3":
                list.add("Category1-3-1");
                list.add("Category1-3-2");
                list.add("Category1-3-3");
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        initSpinner(sp3, list, new SpinnerListener.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(String itemName) {
                // TODO
            }
        });
    }

    private void initSpinner(Spinner spinner, List<String> list, SpinnerListener.Callback callback) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        final AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener = new SpinnerListener(this, callback);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
    }
}
```

The implementation of the OnItemSelectedListener

```
public class SpinnerListener implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private final Context mContext;
    private final Callback mCallback;

    public SpinnerListener(Context context, Callback callback) {
        mContext = context;
        mCallback = callback;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        final String itemName = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "YOUR SELECTION IS : " + itemName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        mCallback.onResult(itemName);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        // Do nothing
    }

    public interface Callback {
        void onResult(String itemName);
    }
}
```

The code can be shorten a little bit if you use lambda function (Java 8). For instance:

```
initSpinner(sp2, list, new SpinnerListener.Callback() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(String itemName) {
                initSpinner3(itemName);
            }
        });
```

can be written:

```
initSpinner(sp2, list, itemName -> initSpinner3(itemName));
```

or even shorter:

```
initSpinner(sp2, list, this::initSpinner3);
```

**EDIT**

Or you can do something like that by using String arrays instead of lists. You can export the methods to init the array into a separated file so it makes the code in the Activity lighter:

```
public class BookActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Spinner sp1, sp2, sp3;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);
        sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp1);
        sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp2);
        sp3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp3);

        initSpinner1();
    }

    private void initSpinner1() {
        final String[] list = SpinnerArrayInitializer.getSpinner1Array();
        initSpinner(sp1, list, itemName -> initSpinner2(itemName));
    }

    private void initSpinner2(String selectedCategory) {
        final String[] list = SpinnerArrayInitializer.getSpinner2Array(selectedCategory);
        initSpinner(sp2, list, itemName -> initSpinner3(itemName));
    }

    public void initSpinner3(String selectedCategory) {
        final String[] list = SpinnerArrayInitializer.getSpinner3Array(selectedCategory);
        initSpinner(sp3, list, itemName -> {
            // TODO
        });
    }

    private void initSpinner(Spinner spinner, String[] list, SpinnerListener.Callback
            callback) {
        final ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        final AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener listener = new SpinnerListener(this, callback);
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(listener);
    }
}
```

And the to initialise the arrays:

```
public interface SpinnerArrayInitializer {

    static String[] getSpinner1Array() {
        return new String[]{"Category1", "Category2", "Category3"};
    }

    static String[] getSpinner2Array(String selectedCategory) {
        switch (selectedCategory) {
            case "Category1":
                return new String[]{"Category1-1", "Category1-2", "Category1-3"};
            case "Category2":
                return new String[]{"Category2-1", "Category2-2", "Category2-3"};
            case "Category3":
                return new String[]{"Category3-1", "Category3-2", "Category3-3"};
            default:
                return new String[0];
        }
    }

    static String[] getSpinner3Array(String selectedCategory) {
        switch (selectedCategory) {
            case "Category1-1":
                return new String[]{"Category1-1-1", "Category1-1-2", "Category1-1-3"};
            case "Category1-2":
                return new String[]{"Category1-2-1", "Category1-2-2", "Category1-2-3"};
            case "Category1-3":
                return new String[]{"Category1-3-1", "Category1-3-2", "Category1-3-3"};
            default:
                return new String[0];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd go for the second approach as you can make the arrays as big as you want it doesn't affect the size of the logic (BookActivity).
After if your arrays are really very big maybe should should use something different to store the data (like a database)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public class BookActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
private final static int SP1_NUM_OF_OPTIONS = 3;
private final static int SP2_NUM_OF_OPTIONS = 3;
private final static int SP3_NUM_OF_OPTIONS = 3;
private final static String SP3_HINT = "<SELECT>";

Spinner sp1, sp2, sp3;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_book);
    sp1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp1);
    sp2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp2);
    sp3 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp3);

    // Setup data list and adapter for sp1.
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=1; i<=SP1_NUM_OF_OPTIONS; i++){
        list.add("Category" + i);
    }
    ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    sp1.setAdapter(adapter);

    // Set listeners for all spinners.
    sp1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sp2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    sp3.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "YOUR SELECTION IS : " + parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    fillSpinnerList(parent.getId(), parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString());

    // Automatically do something different after last step is selected.
    if(parent.getId() == R.id.sp3){
        if(!parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString().equals(SP3_HINT)){
            // Do something
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {}

public void fillSpinnerList(int spinnerId, String selectedSpinnerName){
    ArrayAdapter adapter;
    if(spinnerId == R.id.sp1){
        String[] list1;
        list1 = getResources().getStringArray(getResources().getIdentifier(selectedSpinnerName, "array", getPackageName()));
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list1);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp2.setAdapter(adapter);
    }else if(spinnerId == R.id.sp2){
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(SP3_HINT);
        String[] list1;
        list1 = getResources().getStringArray(getResources().getIdentifier(selectedSpinnerName, "array", getPackageName()));
        list.addAll(Arrays.asList(list1));
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, list);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        sp3.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
}
```

Add your Category in strings.xml:

```
    <array name="Category1">
    <item>Category1_1</item>
    <item>Two</item>
    <item>Three</item>
</array>
<array name="Category1_1">
    <item>Category1_1_1</item>
    <item>Category1_1_2</item>
    <item>Category1_1_3</item>
</array>
<array name="Two">
    <item>Category1_2_1</item>
    <item>Category1_2_2</item>
    <item>Category1_2_3</item>
</array>
<array name="Three">
    <item>Category1_3_1</item>
    <item>Category1_3_2</item>
    <item>Category1_3_3</item>
</array>

<array name="Category2">
    <item>Category2_1</item>
    <item>Four</item>
    <item>Five</item>
</array>
<array name="Category2_1">
    <item>Category2_1_1</item>
    <item>Category2_1_2</item>
    <item>Category2_1_3</item>
</array>
<array name="Four">
    <item>Category2_2_1</item>
    <item>Category2_2_2</item>
    <item>Category2_2_3</item>
    <item>Category2_2_4</item>
</array>
<array name="Five">
    <item>Category2_3_1</item>
    <item>Category2_3_2</item>
    <item>Category2_3_3</item>
    <item>Category2_3_4</item>
    <item>Category2_3_5</item>
</array>

<array name="Category3">
    <item>Category3_1</item>
    <item>Six</item>
    <item>Seven</item>
</array>
<array name="Category3_1">
    <item>Category3_1_1</item>
    <item>Category3_1_2</item>
    <item>Category3_1_3</item>
</array>
<array name="Six">
    <item>Category3_2_1</item>
    <item>Category3_2_2</item>
    <item>Category3_2_3</item>
    <item>Category3_2_4</item>
    <item>Category3_2_5</item>
    <item>Category3_2_6</item>
</array>
<array name="Seven">
    <item>Category3_3_1</item>
    <item>Category3_3_2</item>
    <item>Category3_3_3</item>
    <item>Category3_3_4</item>
    <item>Category3_3_5</item>
    <item>Category3_3_6</item>
    <item>Category3_3_7</item>
</array>
```

Hope it helps!!

Comment: Solution is oke  but my actual data is not Category1 and category1-1 names are different each other but thanks.

Comment: Edited the answer [changes in fillSpinnerList() method]! In strings.xml, you can change the **item** names for spinner2 but be sure you also change the **array** names accordingly.